# Is there a way to conditionally insert using Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, not-exists

We've got a table that has new rows for each updated value. The primary key consists of an ID and a timestamp. There's also a status column. For a particular ID, we'll have a row representing each time that value was updated and we use the one with the most recent timestamp to represent the "current" value.

We have a process that will update the state based on user input. So when a user clicks a button in the UI, a new row will be created with the new state and a new user id.

If two users click the button at the same time, we're just inserting two new records and one of them will win (the one with the newest timestamp). We'd like to avoid having two users click this button at the same time and one potentially creating a new row without knowing they stepped on someone else's state change. In Oracle, we'd just do something like this and check that a row was inserted (where PREVIOUS_KNOWN_MAX_TS is the TS for the "current" record when the user viewed the page):

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE
   (ID, REVISION_TS, USER_ID, STATUS, ...)
SELECT 1, 'SOME_TIMESTAMP', 'user123', 'NEW_STATUS', ...
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
   FROM SOME_TABLE
   WHERE USER_ID = 1
      AND REVISION_TS >= 'PREVIOUS_KNOWN_MAX_TS'));
```

If there was an insert between the time the user viewed the page and the time the user's updated info was inserted, the insert wouldn't happen and we'd detect that by knowing zero rows were inserted.

Is there a way to do this in Hibernate or should we try doing some kind of SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Comment: What about [`saveOrUpdate`](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/09/difference-between-hibernates-saveupdate-and-saveorupdate-methods/) hibernate method?

Comment: I always want to do an insert so save or update won't work. Where I'm having an issue is that sometimes I want to make sure the insert doesn't happen if the database isn't in the state I thought it was in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA - create-if-not-exists entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562105/jpa-create-if-not-exists-entity)

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate your entity class with `org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert` you can override the insert generated by Hibernate.  It's a little tricky though because you have to use the binding parameters in exactly the same way Hibernate's usual insert would use them.