# What is the best pattern for creating an entity if it doesn't exist in JPA

Tags: jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562105/jpa-create-if-not-exists-entity), but very specifically speaks to the problems Pascal points to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3563359/77779).

I need to persist an entity if it does not exist (it's primary key is not in the database), otherwise I need to retry the generation of a new entity and persist that.

We have basically a used record table, where I'm generating random numbers, but I can't have a duplicate (and I can't use a UUID or something like that). So we keep track of the used ones in a table, with the number as the primary key.

How, using JPA, can you ensure that you only create it when it exists, avoiding race conditions? I need to avoid a case where thread one queries if it exists, and then thread two queries, and then thread one inserts and then thread two inserts - duplicate.

The obvious option is to try and catch the exception. The problem is that the transaction is rolled back on an EntityExistsException, but I want to back and persist the next random number, not roll back a transaction.

The ugly solution seems to be to call the persist of the new entity in a separate transaction (so let it roll back). Is there a better practice here?

It would also be nice to know definitively that the cause is the duplication so that the process doesn't keep retrying when the underlying problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

`entityManager.merge()` will do that for you. See the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in this case because the random number also has an associated field (customer it was generated for). In a merge case, it would overwrite that field. But it is a good answer in the abstract.